# Returning specific parent key from a multidimensional array of values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array like this

```
$queryRequest = array(
   "Pub" => array(
      "4bf58dd8d48988d11b941735",
        "52e81612bcbc57f1066b7a06",
        "4bf58dd8d48988d155941735"
    ),
    "Gym" => array(
      "4bf58dd8d48988d175941735"
    )
);
```

I need to create a function that does a look up on an id -- and I need it to return the parent key.

So I have 4bf58dd8d48988d155941735 -- I need it to return Pub

```
$key = array_search($catId, $haystack);
```

didn't work

Comment: Just an example -- but 4bf58dd8d48988d155941735 relates to a pub parent

Comment: they are different id's man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple `foreach`required,You can do it like below:-

```
<?php

$queryRequest = array(
   "Pub" => array(
      "4bf58dd8d48988d11b941735",
        "52e81612bcbc57f1066b7a06",
        "4bf58dd8d48988d155941735"
    ),
    "Gym" => array(
      "4bf58dd8d48988d175941735"
    )
);

function searchparentkey($value,$arr){
   foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
         if(in_array($value,$val)) {
            return $key;
         }
   }

}

echo $parent_key = searchparentkey("4bf58dd8d48988d11b941735",$queryRequest);
```

output:-https://eval.in/635957

Comment: Cheers man - this solved it - yes - the solution was more simple - just getting flustered.

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this:

```
    $queryRequest = array (
        "Pub" => array (
                "4bf58dd8d48988d11b941735",
                "52e81612bcbc57f1066b7a06",
                "4bf58dd8d48988d155941735" 
        ),
        "Gym" => array (
                "4bf58dd8d48988d175941735" 
        ) 
);

function search_key($needle, $haystack)
{
    return array_keys( array_filter( $haystack, function ($v) use($needle) {
        return in_array( $needle, $v );
    } ) );
}

$result = search_key( '52e81612bcbc57f1066b7a06', $queryRequest );
var_dump( $result );
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
<?php
$queryRequest =
Array
(
    (Pub) => Array
        (
            (0) => '4bf58dd8d48988d11b941735',
            (1) => '52e81612bcbc57f1066b7a06',
            (2) => '4bf58dd8d48988d155941735'
        ),

    (Gym) => Array
        (
            (0) => '4bf58dd8d48988d175941735',
        )
);

function searchName($id, $array) {
   foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
       if ($val['0'] === $id) {
           return $key;
       }
   }
   return null;
}

echo searchName('4bf58dd8d48988d11b941735', $queryRequest);
?>
```

[DEMO](https://eval.in/635980)